# How much whitespace is there at the top of a beamer slide and how can I remove it through a theme?

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, vertical-spacing

I am trying to rebuild an existing PowerPoint template with beamer and for this I need precise vertical positioning of the content of a beamer frame. I already found out, how to deal with this for the `headline` and `footline` as well as for the `frametitle`, but how is it for the content? I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\nointerlineskip\begin{tikzpicture}\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum width=\textwidth-2cm,minimum height=1cm,fill=green]{frametitle};\end{tikzpicture}}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\begin{tikzpicture}\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum width=\textwidth-2cm,minimum height=1cm,fill=yellow]{footline};\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \nointerlineskip\begin{tikzpicture}\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum width=\textwidth,minimum height=1cm,fill=orange]{content};\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{~}
\nointerlineskip
\begin{tikzpicture}\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum width=\textwidth,minimum height=1cm,fill=orange]{content};\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{~}
\nointerlineskip
\begin{tikzpicture}\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum width=\textwidth,minimum height=\paperheight-2cm,fill=orange]{content};\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[c]
\frametitle{~}
\nointerlineskip
\begin{tikzpicture}\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum width=\textwidth,minimum height=\paperheight-2cm,fill=orange]{content};\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What I want to achieve is, that the content starts right at the top with no frametitle or just at the lower edge of the frametitle with the `[t]` option and that everything is centered to the area between `frametitle` and `footline`, so when I insert full size images they shall fill the full area instead of having whitespace at the top.

So what I want can be illustrated with this drawing of mine:
[image]

Instead my result looks like this:
[image]

---

How can I achieve to have no vertical white spaces between content and frametitle or content and upper edge? I prefer to be able to do this through adding commands to my theme. Bonus question: Where in beamer can I find the definitions of the whitespaces? And of course I am only looking for vertical alignment, it's clear the the boxes have the wrong width.

---

### After some more investigation, this is what I was looking for, now comes part two of my question

So after playing around and looking into the beamer source, I found how and where the placement options are configured and here is what I actually want:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{MYc}[true]{% centered
    \beamer@frametopskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
    \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
    \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=0pt plus .4\paperheight\relax%
    \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=0pt plus .6\paperheight\relax%
}
\define@key{beamerframe}{MYt}[true]{% top
    \beamer@frametopskip=0pt\relax%
    \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
    \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=\beamer@frametopskip\relax%
    \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=\beamer@framebottomskip\relax%
}
\define@key{beamerframe}{MYb}[true]{% bottom
    \beamer@frametopskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
    \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt\relax%
    \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=\beamer@frametopskip\relax%
    \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=\beamer@framebottomskip\relax%
}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\nointerlineskip\begin{tikzpicture}\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum width=\textwidth-2cm,minimum height=1cm,fill=green]{frametitle};\end{tikzpicture}}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\begin{tikzpicture}\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum width=\textwidth-2cm,minimum height=1cm,fill=yellow]{footline};\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[MYt]
\nointerlineskip
\hspace{1cm}\begin{tikzpicture}\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum width=\textwidth-1cm,minimum height=1cm,fill=orange]{content};\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}



\begin{frame}[MYt]
\frametitle{~}
\vspace*{-0.25em}
\nointerlineskip
\hspace{1cm}\begin{tikzpicture}\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum width=\textwidth-1cm,minimum height=1cm,fill=orange]{content};\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[MYt]
\frametitle{~}
\vspace*{-0.25em}
\nointerlineskip
\hspace{1cm}\begin{tikzpicture}\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum width=\textwidth-1cm,minimum height=\paperheight-5cm,fill=orange]{content};\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[MYc]
\frametitle{~}
\vspace*{-0.25em}
\nointerlineskip
\hspace{1cm}\begin{tikzpicture}\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum width=\textwidth-1cm,minimum height=\paperheight-5cm,fill=orange]{content};\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[MYb]
\frametitle{~}
\vspace*{-0.25em}
\nointerlineskip
\hspace{1cm}\begin{tikzpicture}\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum width=\textwidth-1cm,minimum height=\paperheight-5cm,fill=orange]{content};\end{tikzpicture}
```

\vspace*{-1.3\baselineskip}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

But now I have two problems, the first one is, that if I leave the code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` into my theme, it will only be available for the frame commands, but I would like to call `\documentclass[MYt]{beamer}`. Or the other way around, can I make one of the options the standard behaviour of all frames after the theme has been loaded, so that I can avoid the `[MYt]` after each frame?

And the second problem is, can I put the `\vspace*{-0.25em}\nointerlineskip` that I need for every slide with frametitle and the `\nointerlineskip` that I need for every slide without frametitle somewhere that it is called automatically and the user does not have to take care? The same applies for the `\vspace*{-1.3\baselineskip}` at the bottom, but it is more important for `[MYt]` and `[MYc]` on slides with and without a frametitle.

Comment: You might want to explain a bit more what it actually is you want to do here as it is not clear. Also what are all these tikzpictures used for? That not how beamer styles are normally build.

Comment: @daleif I edited the question, to show what I want to achieve, vs. what I currently get. If you prefer, you can convert all tikzpictures to boxes of the same size. What I want to show is, that there is whitespace added above the content, that I want to get rid of. Does that make sense to you now?

Comment: @daleif I found a principal solution, but I don't know, how to put it into an automatic one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the solution is quite easy, instead of defining new values like `MYt`, we can just override the existing t, b and c keys, as in:

```
\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{c}[true]{% centered
    \beamer@frametopskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
    \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
    \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=0pt plus .4\paperheight\relax%
    \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=0pt plus .6\paperheight\relax%
}
\define@key{beamerframe}{t}[true]{% top
    \beamer@frametopskip=0pt\relax%
    \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
    \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=\beamer@frametopskip\relax%
    \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=\beamer@framebottomskip\relax%
}
\define@key{beamerframe}{b}[true]{% bottom
    \beamer@frametopskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
    \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt\relax%
    \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=\beamer@frametopskip\relax%
    \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=\beamer@framebottomskip\relax%
}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\nointerlineskip\begin{tikzpicture}\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum width=\textwidth-2cm,minimum height=1cm,fill=green]{frametitle};\end{tikzpicture}\vspace*{-0.25em}}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\begin{tikzpicture}\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum width=\textwidth-2cm,minimum height=1cm,fill=yellow]{footline};\end{tikzpicture}}
```

This actually solves the issue